# Catalog Heaven glitch?

Tags: roblox

In Catalog Heaven, when you get a Gravo gun and shoot it, you get a dropped gear.  If you then pick it up, you die.  Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Hey, dude.  I've edited your question to make it more legible.  I would really recommend attempting to add punctuation; I think I got it right, but feel free to edit it some more if I missed something.